# Rails3: ECONNREFUSED Error in Mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I have a controller in a Rails 3 app that, after creating a new object of type WorkRequest, sends an e-mail to the requester. Works for all of my users except one. When she tries it I get the following in the server log.

```
Started POST "/work_requests" for 172.16.42.150 at Mon Aug 08 14:42:53 -0400 2011
  Processing by WorkRequestsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"commit"=>" Save ", "authenticity_token"=>"GhhZ6S0mBaju2zs5Fc7M+u5SoLCke5CRSdVCvLzMK1Q=", "utf8"=>"âœ“", "work_request"=>{"work_due_date"=>"2011-12-01", "person_id"=>"525", "status"=>"Pending", "last_request_date"=>"", "requester_id"=>"5", "pier_module_id"=>"223"}}
Rendered person_mailer/work_request_init_email.html.erb (2.4ms)
Rendered person_mailer/work_request_init_email.text.erb (1.8ms)

Sent mail to hkitzmiller@acponline.org (409ms)
Completed   in 548ms

Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2)):
  app/controllers/work_requests_controller.rb:57:in `create'
  app/controllers/work_requests_controller.rb:54:in `create'
```

It appears to have sent the e-mail (she's left for the day so I can't ask if she received it) but the line it's failing on in the controller the line that invokes the mailer, so I'm not sure.

```
PersonMailer.work_request_init_email(@work_request).deliver
```

Can't seem to find any solid info on what ECONNREFUSED means. Is the mail server refusing the connect (in which case why does it appear the mail was sent?) or is the web server refusing to connect after the mail is sent.

What might cause either server to refuse a connection with this particular user?

Any help would be much appreciated. All the other users of the app seem to be working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This generally is an error caused by a failed connection to the SMTP server. I'd say double check your settings in your environment files (production.rb most likely) and double check the email address. You might also check to see if there's a limit set by the SMTP server.

Comment: Thanks for the response, dogenpunk! I will look at what you suggested and get back.

Comment: Are you using sendmail or SMTP? If it's SMTP, are you using Gmail? I know Gmail has some limits on the number of mails you can send. Also, you should have some credentials in your mail config that your app uses to authenticate to your SMTP server. What's the code in the work_request_init_email method?

Comment: I'm using an SMTP e-mail server internal to our company. And the number of e-mails is very low. There are only a few users in the app, and e-mails get created only when one particular record is created, WorkRequest.

Comment: More investigation shows this works for everyone when I run the application in the development environment. When I run it in production (the same exact instance/code) it fails with this error. Any ideas on what to look at in terms of the difference between dev and prod would be really appreciated!

Comment: Do you have any difference between the action_mailer.config directives in environments/development.rb and environments/production.rb? That would be the first place I'd look. After that, I'd try manually sending an email from your server to the SMTP server via telnet (you know, all that HELO type terminal stuff). Also, try setting your log level in production to debug.

Comment: The only configuration for mail I have in the entire application is in environments.rb, which if I understand correctly, loads in all enviroments and then the others override. But they have nothing for mail. Note: I just tried setting it to use sendmail and I got the same error. And the server can send e-mail in dev mode so I'm not sure the HELO stuff would help but I can try it.

Comment: Double check environments/development.rb and production.db. Most of your config should be in initializers, application.rb and your environment/*.rb files since Rails 3 was released. If it delivers email in dev but not prod, that's about the only place I can think of to look at the moment.

Comment: Well I've gotten it to work by putting the mail configuration stuff in production.rb as well as environments.rb.

I'm not sure why this works. I guess I need to read more on these files. My understanding had been that environments.rb is for things that are the same in all environments and the individual ones were for settings you wanted to override in a certain environment. And odd the mail config settings are not in development.rb and yet it works in development...?

Anyway, thanks again for all your help, dogenpunk. I'm glad it's working, but I will read more to figure why this worked.

Comment: No problem. I know how sticky that stuff can get. Glad it's working now!